# Post a event to application wall on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

the basic idea is, I created a application of which users will become fans and get the latest and greatest events from.
For that I will need to post a event to the wall page of the application itself.

Creating a event is not a problem (I'm using PHP5):

```
 $event_id=$facebook->api_client->events_create(json_encode($FB));
```

But I couldn't find any reference on how to publish a wall entry for that.
This would only show up in the "event" tab
I tried using stream_publish - which works fine, but again I couldn't find a way to create a event.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

create an event and then publish stream with a link to that event ? i dont think u can post events directly to wall

Answer (score 0):

My hubby just figured it out -- because I was trying to gooogle the same answer!  Create your event from your wall!  (There is an event button right there with the link/picture buttons, where you update your status.)

From that event button you fill in the minor details - once it's created, you can go in and edit to add more details.

Comment: I want to do that automated via the API, not by myself every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the answer [create event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109103/how-to-create-a-facebook-event-by-using-facebook-api-in-asp-net/5337582#5337582)